# D8 Body Classes

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8, theming

I'm having a hell of a time trying to get classes on my body element in D8. I'm using a custom theme and the code I have so far looks like this:

**themename.theme**

```
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;

/**
 * Preprocess variables for html templates.
 */
function HOOK_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $path_class = !$variables['root_path'] ? 'path-frontpage' : 'path-' . Html::getClass($variables['root_path']);
  if (isset($path_class)) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = $path_class;
  }
}
```

**html.html.twig**

```
    {%
        set body_classes = [
          not root_path ? 'path-frontpage' : 'path-' ~ root_path|clean_class,
        ]
      %}
<body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }}>
```

I get classes on my body element, but the NID is empty, reading, 'page-node' where I need it to read, 'page-node-NID'.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace HOOK with the name of your theme `mytheme_preprocess_html` otherwise Drupal will not call the hook.